# Reading a text file into list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python. This is a little test program that I made to read a text file into a list. This is the text file:

```
42 1
35 5
50 2
41 6
42 3
48 4
```

And this is my codes:

```
score = [];

for i in range(0, 51):
    score.append(0);

f = open("test1.txt", "r");

for line in f:
    a, b = map(int, f.readline().split());
    score[a] = score[a] + b;

print(score);
```

I'm trying to imitate the array in C++ with list. Read in each line from the text file, first number of the line is the position in the list that will hold the value of the second number. For some reason the program is skipping the 1st, 3rd, 5th lines. This is the result when I run the program.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
```

It was supposed to be

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2]
```

Any idea where I might have done wrong? This is Python 3

Comment: What's with all the semicolons?

Comment: As a side note: `score = [0 for i in range(51)]` or just `score = [0] * 51` would be a simpler way to create an array of 51 zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `for line in f:`, that loops over the file, reading one line at a time.

Then, inside that loop, you ignore `line` and instead do `f.readline()`, which reads the next line.

So, you read line 0, ignore it, read line 1, and process it. Then read line 2, ignore it, read line 3, and process it. And so on.

Just use `line` instead of `f.readline()` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Now I have a problem on  a, b = map(int, line().split())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @NguyenTran: Yes, that's because you're trying to call `line`, which is a string, as if it were a function. Just do `line`, not `line()`.

Answer (score 2):

The readline() call is the problem. You are iterating through each line with `for line in f`, but each time through the loop, you read an *extra* line with `readline()` so it is only reading every other line.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you are iterating through a file with a for each loop, then you can just use the iterative value:

`a, b = map(int, line.split());`